# Printing even/odd on respective lines

Tags: c, nested-loops

I'm trying to print the word * even * on only even lines WITHOUT including the first and second lines (and eventually without the final two lines), but it's printing 15 lines and then randomly throughout it prints an * even *. Using 6 for width, and 15 for height I need a TOTAL of 15 lines, no more and no less.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
int heightCounter, height, width, widthCounter, patternCounter;

patternCounter=0;

printf("enter a number\n");
    scanf("%d", &width);

printf("enter a number\n");
    scanf("%d", &height);

for (heightCounter=1; heightCounter<=height; heightCounter++)
{
    patternCounter++;

    while (patternCounter>2 && patternCounter%2==0)
    {
        printf("*even*\n");
        break;
    }


    for (widthCounter=1; widthCounter<=width; widthCounter++)
    {
        printf("*");

    }

printf("\n");
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the question?  If there is a problem w/ your code, what is it?  And why do you bother with a `while` loop if it unconditionally `break`s?

Comment: I don't honestly know, I'm not sure how to format it using a different loop.

Comment: use `if`instead of `while`

Comment: No need for a loop on the first loop, use an `if` condition instead

Comment: Suggest you use a debugger. That's the perfect tool for helping you understand the execution path of your program.

Answer (score 0):

Use if instead of while and put brackets to define precedence.

```
    If ((patternCounter>2) &&     (patternCounter%2==0))
    {
        printf("*even*\n");
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear in exactly what you are attempting to do, other than *"Using 6 for width, and 15 for height I need a TOTAL of 15 lines, no more and no less.*" From what I gather, correct me if I'm wrong, but you want to take values for `width` and `height` and for the *first two* and *last two* lines in your range of *height* you want to print nothing. For each line in between, if the index is *even* you want to print `"even"` if the line index is *odd*, you want to print `width` `'*'s` for that line.

There are a number of different ways to sort out the logic. However, a few notes. First, always (*always*) validate *user input*. When using the `scanf` family of functions, at minimum, check the `return` to insure the expected number of conversions successfully took place. For example:

```
printf ("enter a number: ");
    if (scanf (" %d", &width) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input (width).\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

While you are free to take user input when needed, in practice, needed values are generally passed as *arguments*. That is what the `int argc` and `char **argv` are for in `int main (int argc, char **argv)`. Take user input when needed, pass values to functions as arguments when possible.

On to the logic. If I understand the goal correctly, then regardless the logic will boil down to iterating over the range of *height* and taking an appropriate action based on the height index for each. 
(*note:* in your example, you can iterate `for (x = 1; x <= height; ...)` but generally in C, you will see the iteration `for (x = 0; x < height; ...)`. both are 100% correct and you are free to iterate from any value to any value, but be aware that all arrays, etc.. are *zero based* making the `0 < x < height` the natural iteration for a range)

As you iterate over each line index, there are three basic conditions you want to check. The first being "*am I the first two or last two lines?*". If so, you want to do nothing and `continue` to the next heither index (the example below just shows the index and outputs `<noprint>` for that line. You next check will be to check whether the index is *even*. If so, you simply print `"even"` and `continue` to the next index.

(*note:* the simplest check is `index & 1` -- if bit `0` is `1` the number is `odd`, consider binary for `2` (`10`) when anded with `1` the result is `0`, and for `3` (`11`) the result is `1`, so your test for even is simply `if ((index & 1) == 0)` `index` is *even*)

The last action you will take (if you haven't *continued* to the next index) is simply to output `width` `'*'s` before going to the next index.

(*note:* when ouputting a single character alone, do not call the variadic `printf` function when all that is needed is outputting a single character. That is like using sledge-hammer as a fly-swatter. Simply use `putchar` or `fputc` instead.)

With that, you could do something similar to the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum { MAXW = 6, MAXH = 15 };       /* constants for width/height */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int w = argc > 1 ? atoi (argv[1]) : MAXW, /* take values from arguments */
        h = argc > 2 ? atoi (argv[2]) : MAXH, /* use MAXW/MAXH for defaults */
        i, j;

    if (w < 0) w = -w;              /* prevent negative values */
    if (h < 0) h = -h;

    for (i = 0; i < h; i++)         /* for each line */
    {
        printf ("%2d : ", i);       /* line index (adjust by 1 if desired */

        if (i < 2 || i > h - 3) {   /* skip 2 on either end of range */
            printf ("<noprint>\n");
            continue;
        }

        if ((i & 1) == 0) {         /* if even (LSB = 0) */
            printf ("even\n");
            continue;
        }

        for (j = 0; j < w; j++)     /* otherwise 1 '*' per-width */
            putchar ('*');
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

For height in the range of `0 - 4`, `<noprint>` is all that is output (showing omitting the first and last 2 lines on either end of range)

```
$ ./bin/evenstar 6 4
 0 : <noprint>
 1 : <noprint>
 2 : <noprint>
 3 : <noprint>
```

For any range `> 4` if the line index is `even` print `even`, otherwise print *width* `'*'s`, e.g

```
 $ ./bin/evenstar 6 7
 0 : <noprint>
 1 : <noprint>
 2 : even
 3 : ******
 4 : even
 5 : <noprint>
 6 : <noprint>
```

For your example of `w = 6` and `h = 15`:

```
$ ./bin/evenstar
 0 : <noprint>
 1 : <noprint>
 2 : even
 3 : ******
 4 : even
 5 : ******
 6 : even
 7 : ******
 8 : even
 9 : ******
10 : even
11 : ******
12 : even
13 : <noprint>
14 : <noprint>
```

In addition to the `if` statement logic above, you could also use a `switch` statement to take appropriate action for each value of the height index. Although here, a simple `if` is probably your best bet. Look it over and let me know if you have any questions or if I've understood what you were trying to accomplish correctly. If not, just let me know and I'm happy to help further.